# Understanding the output of perspective transform in context to the destination points?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to understand the output of [warpPerspective](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html) and [getPerspectiveTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html). So I took an image given as:

[image]

and tried to transform complete image (using the boundary coordinates) into
coordinates as explained by `pts2` below. Here is what I did.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = "b.jpg"

img = cv2.imread(image)

pts1 = np.float32([
        [0,0],
        [0, img.shape[1]],
        [img.shape[0],img.shape[1]],
        [img.shape[0],0]
])


pts2 = np.float32([
        [100,100],
        [100,300],
        [300,300],
        [300,5]
])


M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(400,400))

cv2.imwrite("test.png", dst)
```

The output of the above code looks as follows:

[image]

What does this output mean in terms of the destination coordinates :

```
pts2 = np.float32([
        [100,100],
        [100,300],
        [300,300],
        [300,5]
])
```

Why does the output appear the way it appears right now? I cannot map this in my mind when I see the `pts2` and compare with `pts1` which are simple boundary coordinates.

Comment: Imagine the transformed picture being a postcard that is pinned on a slanted wall.

Comment: Each input corner is moved to the location specified by the corresponding output coordinate. A fractional linear transformation is generated from the 4 pairs of input and output coordinates and all pixels in the image are transformed by the equations generated by the transformation. For each output pixel the equations specify where (x,y as floats) in the input image to grab the color (by interpolating the neighbor colors).